# Write all filenames in folder line per line (skipping filenames without number)

Tags: bash

Hy everyone!

I have many archives with extensions .PNG in the following name:
01.PNG, 02.PNG and so on. Some files are missing: 03.PNG, 05.PNG.

Let have some example: I have this files:

```
01.PNG
02.PNG
04.PNG
06.PNG
```

I want to write the filename number in his respective line:

> 01.PNG
>
> 02.PNG
>
> \n
>
> 04.PNG
>
> \n
>
> 06.PNG

This way I \n where I doesn't have the file.

Anyway to automatize this to all files in folder?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!** You might have the wrong idea about this site; Stack Overflow is a place for professional *(or enthusiast)* programmers to share advice when a problem's solution can't be found elsewhere. The best S.O. Questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question covers a ***specific*** programming problem, algorithm, or software tool, **and** is a practical, answerable problem that is ***unique*** to software development, then you’re in the right place to ask your question! Please see [mcve] and [ask], also [help/on-topic]. You can also [edit] your question.

Comment: You mean, you have to write file names into another file? Could you please confirm once.

Comment: Yes! I have bunch of filenames in folder and want write them in a text file! TY

Comment: @ashleedawg I just want to know the easiest way to make an algorithm to automate this task. Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Scan the current folder and print filename if file exists:

```
for f in {00..99}; do [[ -e $f.PNG ]] && echo $f.PNG || echo; done
```

Comment: Is it linux shell?

Comment: I am using linux `bash 4.4`; where that command was tested OK.